# Anyone have issues with using a RadTextBox in a MultiView?

Tags: exception, textbox, telerik, multiviews

I am want to use a Telerik RadTextBox inside a MultiView in ASP.NET 2.0.  Just dragging a RadTextBox into a view and running the page generates a run-time error of the good old favorite "Object reference nto set to an instance of an object".  It seems to be breaking on the Telerik.WebControls.RadInputControl.SaveViewState() call.

Has anyone any ideas on how to get this to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to be an issue with RadInput for ASP.NET in one of my previous projects at some point. I got latest from the Telerik site and the exception was gone.

Btw, I switched to the ASP.NET AJAX version of the control already and encourage you to try it out. It is more advanced and have RadInputManager as an addition to speed up the performance when having many textboxes on the page.

Dick